# How to set initial compatible to lower than 18 in 18c XE docker image template

Tags: oracle, docker, installation

The plan:

we want to create a docker container with oracle18c XE version with configurable compatibility depending on the current project. So an another project, that currently uses oracle 11.2 or 12.2 can use our image with compatible set to the needed version.

First we add a new variable $COMPATIBLE with default value 18.0.0.0.0

I did following steps:

1. I altered the system in SQLplus and set compatible to a lower version --> of course not possible
2. I replaced compatibility in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/init.ora before run the configure command --> the version $COMPATIBLE is incompatible with 18.0.0
3. So I changed the compatible parameter in the template file /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/assistants/dbca/templates/XE_Database.dbc --> the version $COMPATIBLE is incompatible with 18.0.0
4. I tried to generate scripts from the template using dbca su -s /bin/bash oracle -c "/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/dbca -silent -generateScripts -gdbName XE -templateName XE_Database.dbc" and run the configuration with the generated scripts--> this brought me a lot of failings during the run, so it configures nothing in the end
5. I recreated the template using dbca and the original XE_Database.dbc template and changed only the compatible parameter, than changed the template name in oracle-xe18 configure  bash script method before run it and still incompatible with 18.0.0. in the tempSeed.ctl

Please help

Comment: Do you have some Dockerfile in the result to see? I didn't get what do you call as template.

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust compatibility parameter too much. There was Oracle document describing optimizer parameters to make 12c backward compatible with 11c and it was very long. "compatible" is not the only parameter to deal with.

Moreover you should check sqlnet.ora parameter SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=..
Otherwise JDBC drivers 11c might not be able to logon.